# How to disable 'page' Output event being called on Scroll in ngx-datatable?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I don't want infinite scroll pagination. Instead I just want to called pagination on clicking page number in the footer alone. I am using serverside pagination. So triggering 'page' event on every scroll is causing my pagination api to fire too many requests which my server can't handle.

Basically how do I disable Infinite scrolling with Server side paging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around this problem by handling the (scroll) output in ngx-datatable. The idea is to use a flag to suppress paging when the scroll event gets called and then enable it again after a timeout. Something like this.

Template

```
<ngx-datatable (page)="doPaging($event)" (scroll)="handleScroll()">...</ngx-datatable>
```

In you component

```
scrollTimeout: any;
suppressPaging: boolean = false;
doPagining() {
  if (!this.suppressPagining) {
    //do paging
  }
}

handleScroll() {
   this.suppressPagining = true;

   if (this.scrollTimeout) {
        celarTimeout(this.scrollTimeout);
   }

  this.scrollTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
     this.suppressPagining = false;
  }, 100)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[virtualization]="false" solved the problem to me